# order of constructor component calls

Tags: c++

What order are these parts of a constructor called in?

```
myClass::myClass(otherClass c) // part 1
 : baseClass(thing)            // part 2
{                              // part 3
    thing = c;
}
```

Is it 1, 3, 2?

Comment: Have you tried testing it yourself? Add `println`s to each constructor and see what order they get called in :)

Comment: @KshitijMehta I always thought `println` was a Java thing

Comment: Can't believe I messed that up! I'm programming in Java as I type this, and I just typed println subconsciously! Totally meant `cout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2,3.

First arguments are evaluated. Then initialization. Then the body of the function.

---

Order of arguments is unspecified.

Order of ctor init list is order of members in the class body.

Comment: so you're saying my code would pass an un-initialised `Thing` object to the base class?

Comment: is the body of the function called before the initialisation of the parent class? I mean, do constructors overlap at all in an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @SirYakalot The base class constructor finishes before the derived class's is called.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 doesn't result in any evaluation; it describes how to call the
function, and names the arguments (which of course must be evaluated to
call the function.

Initialization occurs **before** the constructor body is entered.  First
all virtual base classes are initialized, in the order resulting from a
depth first left to right search of the inheritance hierarchy, then all
non-virtual base classes are initialized, in the left to right order in
which they appear in the class definition, and finally the members are
initialized, in the order they are declared in the class definition. 
Note that the order in which the initializers appear in the constructor
has no effect on the order.

Finally, the constructor body (your part 3) is executed.